# Add then remove class after delay but without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout, removeclass

I am adding a class `.error` on click and now after time interval of 2 seconds I want to remove this class, but without page reload/refresh.I used `delay()` in jQuery as:

```
$('#username').addClass('error').delay(2000).removeClass('error');
```

but it's not working.

Then I tried `setTimeout()`.

It's working, but reloading page. I want something that would add, and then remove, class after specific time but do not refresh/reload the page.

Please help, and thank you in advance.

Comment: can't use `delay()` for methods that aren't *"queueable"* like animations. Please show your code. No reason that `setTimeout()` would reload page by itself

Comment: This is my code (and its reloading the page which is not wanted): 

$('#username').addClass('error').setTimeout(function(){  
  $(this).removeClass('error');
 },2000);

Comment: that will throw error because you are trying to chain `setTimeout()` as jQuery method when it is a global window function. My guess is you are using this in a form submit handler and the error breaks the submit handler and form gets submitted by default process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery and setTimeout function:

```js
var $elm = $("#username").addClass("error");
setTimeout(function() {
  $elm.removeClass("error");
}, 2000);
```

```css
.error{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="username">USER NAME</div>
```

Comment: This is the jQuery answer.

Comment: @doug65536 Yes, because the OP tried in jquery not in pure javascript, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```js
var element = document.getElementById('username');

element.classList.add('error');

window.setTimeout(function () {
  element.classList.remove('error');
}, 2000);
```

```css
#username {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .25s linear;
}
#username.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="username">Username</div>
```

Comment: That's not really necessary. If the class is already there it will just not add it.

Comment: Yes, but 2 seconds later it will remove it, which may be unexpected.

Comment: No, it wont be unexpected. That method will also fail in the same way.

Comment: @Tomato The whole point of functions that "add class" and "remove class" is handling duplicate/missing classes. You don't redundantly `if` around them.

Comment: The question is tagged jquery. This is pure JS.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Probably why OP didn't accept my answer.

Comment: Still useful though, pure js person with similar problem might land here.